# Loading JSON schema including fragments

Tags: json, ruby

An application on which I'm working needs to validate some data against JSON schemas. These are read from file and stored in a database, e.g.:

```
reader = JSON::Schema::Reader.new(
      accept_uri: false,
      accept_file: true
)
schema = reader.read("schema_file.json")
saved_schema = SavedSchema.create(schema: schema.schema)

# Later:

validation = JSON::Validator.fully_validate(saved_schema.schema, data)
```

This is effective until schema_file.json contains a reference to a fragment, such as:

```
"associated_tools": {
   "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "description": "Links to associated tools",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "associated_tools_fragment.json#tool"
      }
    }
  },
```

The `associated_tools_fragment.json` file is in the same directory as `schema_file.json` referenced above.

In this case the validation step fails as the validator tries to find `associated_tools_fragment.json` but it doesn't know in which directory to look. So, I can think of two things that might help:

1. Specify the path in which the validator must look for fragments, or (preferred)...
2. Load the fragment when the schema is parsed.

I can't find anything that explains how to do either of those - does anyone know?

Comment: Did you check this section https://github.com/ruby-json-schema/json-schema#controlling-remote-schema-reading ? I think you might need a customized schema reader in your case if you want the fragments to be validated too, or just disable resolving refs to skip the references...

Comment: I did see that document. At first glance it didn't seem to offer any means of reading files locally do do what I'm after, though it gives the impression that I could make the fragments available via the web and restrict reading to that domain. Not great, but it might have to do if there's no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I had to do this myself. Since all the fragments are of the same format, the following was possible:

```rb
  def read_schema(filename)
    reader = JSON::Schema::Reader.new(
      accept_uri: false,
      accept_file: true
    )
    schema = reader.read("#{Rails.root}/lib/record_schemas/#{filename}").schema
    return schema unless schema.has_key?('properties')

    schema['properties'].each_key do |key|
      fragment = schema['properties'].dig(key, 'items')
      next unless fragment

      ref = fragment['$ref']
      next unless ref

      next unless ref.start_with?('fragments/')

      file, type = ref.split('#')

      unless schema.has_key?('definitions')
        schema['definitions'] = {}
      end
      schema['definitions'][type] = read_fragment(file, type)
      schema['properties'][key]['items']['$ref'] = "#/definitions/#{type}"
    end
    schema
  end

  def read_fragment(file, key)
    reader = JSON::Schema::Reader.new(
        accept_uri: false,
        accept_file: true
    )
    schema = reader.read("#{Rails.root}/lib/record_schemas/#{file}").schema
    schema['definitions'][key]
  end
```

This looks for any references to a fragment in a schema and, if it finds one, converts the reference to an internal one and loads the fragment's definition into the schema.